# How do I keep Access control modules from interfering with a view page?

Tags: views

I've been trying to add access control to my page I'm working on recently. And I've run into a major issue so far.

I have a view page that is set to allow anyone with the permission to view their own unpublished content. Anytime I enabled acl or og_access and rebuild the permissions that view page is ended up acces denied to any non-admin user. I've tried changine the views permissions and recreating it completely, but for some reason trying to get this build to do this one thing is not working.

If I turn off access controls and rebuild permissions everything is fine, but I need access control.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be helpful.

Views Version 7.x-3.14
Access Control List Version 7.x-1.1
OG Access Version 7.x-2.9

Comment: Can you add a version tag? Also make sure if it is the view, or the content (my best guess would be that the view's no result behavior is set to show the Access denied page and the real problem is that those modules prevent the user access to its own unpublished content, so views has no results).

Comment: I can add versioning tags if that helps no problem. And if the issue is the module preventing that permission... and even that permission on published content how would I fix the issue?

Comment: I suppose the module defines another permission for this (probably per content type), which you may have disabled (forget to enable). Maybe you need them both (per content type and global unpublished content permission).

Comment: So I changed a users role to administrator and hopped on Masquerade so I could explore the issue... if I set the user to admin they get a list of nodes they are supposed to. Anything else isn't. reguardless of the content permissions.